# ¿Como cambiar formato de fecha recibido por $_POST?

Tags: php, html, date

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación con `PHP` y `HTML`, y me veo en la necesidad de cambiar el formato del `<input type="date"/>` ya que es el formato inglés y lo necesito en el español.

No tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, he leído que usando  `date_format($fechaNacimiento, 'd/m/y')` esa función o también usando la función de date como esta:

```html
$fecha = new DateTime('2017-02-01');
$fecha_m_d_y = $fecha->format('d/m/Y');

echo $fecha_m_d_y;
```

Pero ninguna de las dos he sabido aplicarlas, porque necesito aplicarlo a un `$_POST` y para estas funciones son `string`, y no se como pasar el `$_POST` a `string`. Adjunto código

**HTML Y PHP**

```
              <tr>
                <td>Fecha Nacimiento:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="jug_fec_nac" id="jug_fec_nac" value="<?php echo date_format($fechaNacimiento, 'd/m/y');
                ?>"/></td>
              </tr>
```

**Definición de variables**

```
$fechaNacimiento = $_POST['jug_fec_nac'];
```

Eso me devuelve la fecha con formato ingles (`2017/05/31`) y yo la necesito que al recibirla por el `$_POST` la cambie a (`31/05/2017`)

Comment: ¿No sera que quieres convertir la fecha `2017/05/31` a la fecha con formato `31/05/2017`?

Comment: @Marcos exactamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de las siguientes formas:

### Solución 1

Usando [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
<?php
// Fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $_POST['jug_fec_nac']);
// Fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy
$fechaNacimiento = $fecha->format('d/m/Y');
```

### Solución 2:

Usando [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) y [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php)

```
<?php
// Como la fecha viene en formato ingles, establecemos el localismo.
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

// Fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['jug_fec_nac']);

// Fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy
$fechaNacimiento = strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Mil gracias @Marcos la segunda solución ha sido la que me ha resuelto el problema. De nuevo mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta forma para modificar el formato de fecha http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php

Pero yo te aconsejo que cambies el type de tu formulario en vez de poner "text" intenta poner "date" posiblemente así te resulte mejor al aplicar el método POST
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp